# How to publish an iOS App on behalf of a client?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've just finished an iOS app. Now I need to publish it to the app store using my client's account. I want to be sure that what I'm about to do is the correct path.

That is:

1. Create the developer certificate using the client's credentials
2. Build the app using the new developer certificate
3. Publish and everything else using the client's account

The only other thing that I thought would be to register myself as a developer on his account. However I think at some point I will need the his account to finishing the process. Is that correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need a team  agent role to publish the app..

Comment: He needs to create a distribution certificate to publish right?  He mentions developer certificate which I thought was for testing only?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need his account to finish the process and actually sign the App file that you send to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

you need to be a "Admin" type user @ the developer portal and on itunesConnect.
With Admin user, you can create all sorts of certificates and provisioning that you may require from developing to deployment of an app from any developer account.

Comment: are you sure you don't mean "agent" type?  If not, then how to "admins" publish the apps for their clients/team agents?